# Are there any bitblt alternatives without the slowness?

Tags: c++, windows, graphics, 2d, bitblt

Recently it's come to my attention that bitblt is extrodinarily slow (taking around 33 ms for 1 image) and I know it's not that my hardware is too slow because it runs games with decent graphics at around 50 fps. So, what alternatives to bitblt exist that I can use to achieve the same result?

I'm running Windows XP

Here is the code I'm using:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tgmath.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void rotatebmp (HDC hdc_x, float q, float x0, float y0)
{
  q = (q * 0.01745333055);
  XFORM blah;
  blah.eM11 = cos(q);
  blah.eM12 = sin(q);
  blah.eM21 = -sin(q);
  blah.eM22 = cos(q);
  blah.eDx = x0 - cos(q)*x0 + sin(q)*y0;
  blah.eDy = y0 - cos(q)*y0 - sin(q)*x0;
  SetWorldTransform(hdc_x, &blah);
  return;
}

int main()
{
  float q = 0;
  HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
  HBITMAP cross = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, ("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Death\\My Documents\\45Hand.bmp") ,IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
  HBITMAP crossmask = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, ("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Death\\My Documents\\45Hand2.bmp") ,IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
  timeBeginPeriod(1);
  DWORD totalt = 0;
  while (1)
  {
    DWORD startt = timeGetTime();
    float tfactor = (totalt * 0.01);
    tfactor = (3.6 * tfactor);
    q = (q + tfactor);
    HDC hdc_x = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);
    SetGraphicsMode(hdc_x, GM_ADVANCED);
    SelectObject(hdc, crossmask);
    rotatebmp (hdc_x, q, 850, 375);
    BitBlt(hdc_x,550,0,600,527,hdc,0,0, SRCAND);
    ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP,hdc_x);
    hdc_x = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);
    SetGraphicsMode(hdc_x, GM_ADVANCED);
    SelectObject(hdc, cross);
    rotatebmp (hdc_x, q, 850, 375);
    BitBlt(hdc_x,550,0,600,527,hdc,0,0, SRCPAINT);
    ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP,hdc_x);
    Sleep(10);
    DWORD endt = timeGetTime();
    totalt = (endt - startt);
  }
  timeEndPeriod(1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What operating system are you running on, and which 2D libraries are you using?

Comment: I don't know which 2D libraries I'm using, I think none.. maybe GDI?

Comment: Are the source and destination on the same device? Cross-device bitblt is slow because all the pixels have to be transferred across the bus.

Comment: No, I'm not sure how I would go about transfering from the source to the destination on the same device (the desktop) without things going wacky.. is it possible? I've added the source code to my question